# Why is WP template_include overwritting all templates rather than specified page?

Tags: plugins, functions, templates, actions, template-include

I have created a custom plugin for WP that has an action that includes a template via `template_include` as shown here:

```
public function __construct( $wp_custom_plugin, $version ) {

    $this->wp_custom_plugin = $wp_custom_plugin;
    $this->version = $version;

    add_action('template_include', array( $this, 'add_my_template' ));    

}
```

Here is the function that references the template:

```
public function add_my_template($template){
  if ( is_page( 'my-unique-page' ) ) {
      $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'page-my-unique-page.php' ;
      return $template;
    }
  }
}
```

Okay, so my expectation here is that i would only see this template on `my-site.com/my-unique-page`.  In practice I am not seeing this restriction, but rather the template is applied site wide.  Any suggestions on how I can modify to limit the display to the single page?  Thanks.

Comment: You may need to remove the `return $template;` line out of the 'if' statement, so cut and paste it just before the closing `}` of the `add_my_template` function. You should return the template even if you didn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WebElaine's comment.  I needed to move the template return outside of the function so that it looks like this:

```
public function add_my_template($template){
  if ( is_page( 'my-unique-page' ) ) {
    $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'page-my-unique-page.php' ;
  }
  return $template;
}
```